# How to write input to a text file in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to write console input `Console.ReadLine` to a text file.

It is hard find it anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is file already created?

Comment: Show us your code and the errors and we can then help you.  Rather than just give you code that you might not understand (You can google for that!)

Comment: yes it is already created

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: "It's hard to find anywhere"... apart from the Microsoft website, which is the first google result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Comment: If the file is already created, instead the `WriteAllText` you should call [File.AppendAlLText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_AppendAllText_System_String_System_String)

Comment: "_It is hard find it anywhere._". Take your previous sentence. remove all necessary words. 
 " ̶I̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ **write** ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶o̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶(̶C̶o̶n̶s̶o̶l̶e̶.̶R̶e̶a̶d̶L̶i̶n̶e̶)̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶ **text file**".
 
 Add the language. And "Write text file C#" in any order will give you good result on any search engigne.
 Like [How to write to a text file (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: thank you for all of the great answers, I used this answer:
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.txt", Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't tell whether the text file already exists or not, you may want-

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser\test.txt";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    using FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
}
```

The code above checks whether file exists or not; if no, creates the file. 
If you want append text to file, not overwrite:

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser\test.txt";
File.AppendAllText(path, "some text");
```

If you want append text to file in a new line, not overwrite:

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser\test.txt";
File.AppendAllText(path, Environment.NewLine + "some text");
```

If you want overwrite the text file:

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser\test.txt";
File.WriteAllText(path, "some text");
```

If you have name of the file separated:

```cs
string sepratedPath = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser"
string sepratedFileName = "test.txt";

string path = Path.Combine(sepratedPath, sepratedFileName);
```

If you want append items of an array line by line:

```cs
string path = @"C:\Users\power\Desktop\Tor Browser\test.txt";
string[] lines = { "New line 1", "New line 2" };
File.AppendAllLines(path, lines);
```

Do not forget `using System.IO;`.

My research:

- [How to: Write text to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file)
- [Create a Text File in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/create-a-text-file-in-C-Sharp/)
- [File.Exists(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream([file-path], System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
    writer.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
```

thank u,